# Column Level encryption, select query in stored procedure with where clause is not working

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Below are the scripts for table and insert

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[registration]
(
    [Email] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Address] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO registration 
VALUES ('sample1@test.com', 'Sample1', 'New Jersey'),
       ('sample2@test.com', 'Sample2', 'New York'),
       ('sample3@test.com', 'Sample3', 'Chicago');
```

Enabled column level encryption on Email field, by creating Always encrypt Keys (Column Master Keys and Column Encryption Keys). Logged into SSMS with "Enable Always Encrypted"

Created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prod_getregistration
    @Email VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM registration 
    WHERE Email = @Email
END

prod_getregistration 'sampletest@test.com'
```

When execute the procedure, I get this error:

> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'MY_CEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Sample') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Is `where` clause possible on encrypted columns?

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using a `varchar(MAX)` to store things like a name, address and Email? I doubt there is anyone in the world who has 2147483648 characters in their name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102756/parameterizationalways-encrypted-inside-stored-proc

Comment: All fields are encrypted i want to make sure size is not causing this error that's why i have given varchar(max), anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question simply, yes, the where clause is possible on encrypted columns using Always Encrypted.

With that said, the issue you are facing here is due to how the server is executing the procedure. To understand what is happening here we need to know how the column in the table has changed once it has been encrypted. Before the encryption process, the column is storing data as plain text

[image]

After it gets encrypted the data is converted to a binary data. You can see evidence of this by connecting to the database with and without the Always Encrypted feature enabled and querying the table. Now you see the Hex representation of the binary data in the encrypted email column.

[image: Query without Always Encrypted Enabled]

With the procedure being executed as defined above, the server is trying to compare the plain-text email to the encrypted cipher-text value which is causing you to see the type clash.

By [using parameterization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/) when calling the procedure, the query parameter will be encrypted before being sent to the server so that the query cipher-text value and the database cipher-text value will be compared. The following change to your call to the stored procedure should work for you.

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(MAX) = 'sample2@test.com'
EXEC prod_getregistration @value
```

[image]